# Spring MVC won't call requestmapping function contains pathvariable

Tags: spring-mvc

My Spring MVC can call the normal controller functions but can not call the function contains pathvariable.

I have two links ***/myapp/projects*** and ***/myapp/project/{name}***

the first link works well in my controller, but the second link can not call my controller function. The web.xml should be correct. Since the error is following:

[image]

my web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/projects</url-pattern>       
    <url-pattern>/project/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

my controller:

```
@Controller
public class ProjectsController {
    static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ProjectsController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/projects", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getInstances(Model model)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("=====projects====");
        return "release-projects";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/project/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDetails(@PathVariable("name") String name, Model model) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("=====project details====");
        model.addAttribute("model", "111");
        return "project_details";
    }

}
```

Comment: why not use <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> instead of multiple url pattern ?

Comment: I have multiple old links and they are not using controller. For the new added links we would like to use spring MVC.

Comment: okay try creating two separate servlet mappings for each url.

Comment: check the browser console(by doing inspect element) to see the error

Comment: The page has no useful information. It shows the element of a http 404 error page.

Comment: The controller setup seems OK. Are you sure there is a "project_details" view where the view resolver expects it to be?

Comment: Yes, I have this. It doesn't call the function since it doesn't print "===project details====". If I change <url-pattern> and RequestMapping to /project/myProject to not use PathVariable, everything works. So the problem is that if I use PathVariable in my value then it doesn't work.